# Create Resource on Django Tastypie with a Java POST request but getting 500 error code

Tags: java, django, json, rest, tastypie

I am trying to post a new resource to a django tastypie API with a Java Client, but i am getting a Http 500 error code.
Basically i am just trying to make a new reservation on my api from the client.

Models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    reserv_date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    reserv_finish = models.DateTimeField()
    penalty = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

Resources:

```
class AuthorResource(ModelResource):
    #user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Author.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'author'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

class ProductResource(ModelResource):
    author = fields.ForeignKey(AuthorResource, 'author')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'product'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

class ReservationResource(ModelResource):
    product = fields.ForeignKey(ProductResource, 'product')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'reservation'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

My json that i am posting (i am using java simple json and i am getting the backslashes and i don't know how to take it out):

```
public JSONObject encodeJsonObject(Reservation reservation){
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("id",String.valueOf(reservation.getId()));
    obj.put("product","/api/reservation/product/"+reservation.getProduct().getId()+"/");      
    obj.put("reserv_date_start",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+00:00'").format(reservation.getReserv_date_start()));
    obj.put("reserv_finish",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+00:00'").format(reservation.getReserv_finish()));        
    obj.put("resource_uri", "/api/reservation/reservation/"+reservation.getId()+"/");
    obj.put("penalty",reservation.isPenalty());
    return obj;
}
```

---

```
json: {
"product": "\/api\/reservation\/product\/12\/",
"id": "7",
"reserv_finish": "2013-01-05T23:11:51+00:00",
"resource_uri": "\/api\/reservation\/reservation\/7\/",
"penalty": false,
"reserv_date_start": "2013-01-05T23:11:51+00:00"
```

}

---

My client to post code:

```
public void apacheHttpClientPost(String url, String user, char[] pass, JSONObject data) {
     try {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, new String(pass)));
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(data.toJSONString());
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    postRequest.setEntity(input);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

}
```

one of the debug errors:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:808:
>   RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-01-04
>   17:31:57) while time zone support is active.   RuntimeWarning)

i am posting to

> "http://localhost:8000/api/reservation/reservation/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. the problem was in my json that was incomplete. i had a foreign key to my user resource that i didn't add. here is the solution:

json:

```
{
    "product": "\/api\/reservation\/product\/12\/",
    "id": "7",
    "reserv_finish": "2013-01-06T15:26:15+00:00",
    "resource_uri": "\/api\/reservation\/reservation\/7\/",
    "penalty": false,
    "reserv_date_start": "2013-01-06T15:26:15+00:00",
    "user": "\/api\/reservation\/auth\/user\/1\/"
}
```

resource:

```
class ReservationResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    product = fields.ForeignKey(ProductResource, 'product')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'reservation'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

java client code:

```
public JSONObject encodeJsonObject(Reservation reservation){
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("id",String.valueOf(reservation.getId()));  
    obj.put("product","/api/reservation/product/"+reservation.getProduct().getId()+"/");      
    obj.put("reserv_date_start",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+00:00'").format(reservation.getReserv_date_start()));
    obj.put("reserv_finish",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+00:00'").format(reservation.getReserv_finish()));        
    obj.put("resource_uri", "/api/reservation/reservation/"+reservation.getId()+"/");
    obj.put("user", "/api/reservation/auth/user/1/"); //not dynamic yet
    obj.put("penalty",reservation.isPenalty());
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Datetimes in your JSON are missing the timezone part:

```
json: {
    "product": "\/api\/reservation\/product\/9\/",
    "id": "6",
    "reserv_finish": "2013-01-04T17:31:57",                 // <-- Here
    "resource_uri": "\/api\/reservation\/reservation\/6\/",
    "penalty": false,
    "reserv_date_start": "2013-01-04T17:31:57"              // <-- And here
}
```

ISO-8601 datetimes should look like this:

```
"2013-01-04T17:31:57+00:00"
                    ^^^^^^^
```

Also, which `python-dateutil` version you have installed? Can you check this please?

```
pip freeze | grep dateutil
```

### Other things worth looking at:

- [TASTYPIE_DATETIME_FORMATTING](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#tastypie-datetime-formatting) in Tastypie docs.
- [Time zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) in Django docs.

Comment: i did your command for date util and got "Warning: cannot find svn location for distribute==0.6.24dev-r0
python-dateutil==1.5". going to try the changes you suggested now.Will let you know if it works

Comment: changed my code above with your ideas and i still get a 500 error. my new json is edited. Are the urls ok even with the backslaches?

Comment: I don't think the backslashes are ok, but the error message is clearly related to datetimes. Do you get the same error message after adding that `+00:00` part?

Comment: I hope you realize that in production code that last part should be the actual time zone, for example `-03:00` if you're in Brazil..

Comment: Just tried a roughly equivalent POST (with `curl`) and the it seems that the extra slashes are parsed without problems.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem here. Even posting a "naive" date works. Can you describe your installation? Which Django and Tastypie versions? Wich OS and version?

Comment: Yah same error. I dont think its the datetime cause its only a warning. is my tastypie resource code ok for you? Isnt it something missing to accept post requests? Can't i debug from the tastypie? Anyways i im using django 1.4 and django-tastypie==0.9.11